# burrow.io (localhost tunneling service) returns HTTP 400 when accessing my webapi, while working for another port

Tags: http, http-tunneling

I want to debug my application (Angular app) using appetize.io for testing on an iPad app.  I decided to tunnel my localhost online so I can access the app in appetize.io iOS emulator.

When I tunnel my app I encounter the following issue:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

This is when I map localhost:63399 to the public url
However, the localhost:3000 does not exhibit this issue.  It works.

For security, I can not post the urls I generate.

**How do I successfully tunnel my api via burrow.io?**